# How to modify values in a list of lists based on a sub-value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a great challenge trying to resolve this. I have this list of lists:

```
[['060710080013011', 9],
 ['060710080013011', 9],
 ['060710080013011', 9],
 ['060710080013011', 9],
 ['060710080013011', 9],
 ['060710080013011', 9],
 ['060710080013011', 9],
 ['060710080013011', 9],
 ['060710080013011', 9],
 ['060710080013033', 8],
 ['060710080013033', 8],
 ['060710080013033', 8],
 ['060710080013033', 8],
 ['060710080013033', 8],
 ['060710080013033', 8],
 ['060710080013033', 8],
 ['060710080013033', 8],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15],
 ['060710080021000', 15]]
```

The first value is an ID and the second value is how many times this ID is appearing on the list of lists. The problem is the following:

When the second value is greater than 7, I need to change the values in every second item in each tuple, **here the desired output:**

```
[['060710080013011', 7],
 ['060710080013011', 7],
 ['060710080013011', 7],
 ['060710080013011', 7],
 ['060710080013011', 7],
 ['060710080013011', 7],
 ['060710080013011', 7],
 ['060710080013011_2', 2],
 ['060710080013011_2', 2],
 ['060710080013033', 7],
 ['060710080013033', 7],
 ['060710080013033', 7],
 ['060710080013033', 7],
 ['060710080013033', 7],
 ['060710080013033', 7],
 ['060710080013033', 7],
 ['060710080013033_2', 1],
 ['060710080021000', 7],
 ['060710080021000', 7],
 ['060710080021000', 7],
 ['060710080021000', 7],
 ['060710080021000', 7],
 ['060710080021000', 7],
 ['060710080021000', 7],
 ['060710080021000_2', 7],
 ['060710080021000_2', 7],
 ['060710080021000_2', 7],
 ['060710080021000_2', 7],
 ['060710080021000_2', 7],
 ['060710080021000_2', 7],
 ['060710080021000_2', 7],
 ['060710080021000_3', 1]]
```

If you see my desire output above I need to change the second item of every sublist that has a number greater than 7.

If you need clarification ask me, my first language is not English but I can do my best.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the change you are trying to make to the tuple. If i understand correctly, the second value in each tuple is a "count" of the ID, and this is the value you want to change if it exceeds 7, what do you want to change it to?

in your result you have 3 values in the tuple instead of 2, are you adding this as well as changing the value of the 2nd item?

Comment: Could you explain your desired output a little? Give an example of actual input and what the desired output for that should be. That would help in clarifying the question.

Comment: if I am correct.
`[123456789, 9]` you would want to be corrected to `[123456789, 7], [123456789_2, 2]` is this correct?

Comment: Thank you for you time @JamesLingham. Basically, if you si the input value, the first 9 sublists in the LIST have the same ID and as a second sub value, all this have 9. So basically I need to change the 9 for a 7 to the first 7 values and a 2 for the last 2. Does it make sense. please feel free to ask.

Comment: so creating a new ID for the last 2 occurrences? where does the 3rd value in the tuple come from? 155 etc, it seems to carry over to the new set of ID's too, but does not appear in your first list.

Comment: @user2731223 Hello. Thank you for your time. Sorry for the confusion. English is not my first language. So the fist List of Lists is a real input and the second list in my question is my desired output. Please feel free to ask me as many questions you want. Again sorry for the confusion.

Comment: for example, if i have the list input `[['100', 9]]` I should get `[['100', 7], ['100_2', 2]]` as the output?

Comment: @JamesLingham I have fixed my result list, you are right. Also, your example is not what I need. In a list of 9 sublist , ['[100 , 9],[100,9].......] I want to change the fist 7 values as [[100,7],[100,7]......[100_2,2],[100_2,2]

Comment: @CesarJhonatanGarridoLeccaR thanks, I didn't want to waste space typing in out all the time, I've updated with an answer I believe should work, tested my end and gives the output i think you want. let me know if it is still wrong.

Comment: @JamesLingham Thank you so much, James. I saw your update. I will test it. Thank you for your patience with my English limitations.

Answer (score 0):

```
lista2 = [['100',9]]
for l in lista2:
    v = l[1] - 7
    c = 2
    while v > 0:
        l[1] = 7
        lista2.append([l[0]+"_"+str(c),min(v,7)])
        v -= 7
        c += 1

print(lista2)
```

should work as you have requested, mainly some syntax errors and misnamed variables in your code, please let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much @James . Again sorry for the confusion. What I need is in a list of 9 sublists : lista2 = [['100',9].........[100;9] get another list of 9 sublist like this: [[100,7],[100,7]....[100_2,2],[100_2,2). This becouse 9-7 = 2 , so the residual should be the second value.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me with this. I will try your code!. It seems that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution will be to use **groupby** and a simple **Counter**, here's a working solution:

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: from collections import Counter

In [3]: whatever = [['060710080013011', 9],  ['060710080013011', 9],  ['060710080013011', 9],  ['060710080013011', 9],  ['06071008001
   ...: 3011', 9],  ['060710080013011', 9],  ['060710080013011', 9],  ['060710080013011', 9],  ['060710080013011', 9],  ['06071008001
   ...: 3033', 8],  ['060710080013033', 8],  ['060710080013033', 8],  ['060710080013033', 8],  ['060710080013033', 8],  ['06071008001
   ...: 3033', 8],  ['060710080013033', 8],  ['060710080013033', 8],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080
   ...: 021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['0607
   ...: 10080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  [
   ...: '060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15],  ['060710080021000', 15]]

In [7]: counter = []
    ...: # we use groupby to group the inner list by key, i.e. the first label
    ...: for key, grouped in groupby(whatever, lambda x: x[0]):
    ...:     # here, we decide if we need to append the label if the item counts great than multiple of 7
    ...:     for idx, item in enumerate(grouped):
    ...:         # to get the LABEL_INDEX as new keyed
                 keyed = key if int(idx / 7) == 0 else "{}_{}".format(key, int(idx / 7) + 1)
    ...:         counter.append(keyed)
    ...: # simply use a counter to re-count the new label items
    ...: counted = Counter(counter)
    ...: answer = []
    ...: for keyed in sorted(counted):
    ...:     for _ in range(counted[keyed]):
    ...:         answer.append([keyed, counted[keyed]])
    ...:
    ...: print(answer)
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:

[['060710080013011', 7], ['060710080013011', 7], ['060710080013011', 7], ['060710080013011', 7], ['060710080013011', 7], ['060710080013011', 7], ['060710080013011', 7], ['060710080013011_2', 2], ['060710080013011_2', 2], ['060710080013033', 7], ['060710080013033', 7], ['060710080013033', 7], ['060710080013033', 7], ['060710080013033', 7], ['060710080013033', 7], ['060710080013033', 7], ['060710080013033_2', 1], ['060710080021000', 7], ['060710080021000', 7], ['060710080021000', 7], ['060710080021000', 7], ['060710080021000', 7], ['060710080021000', 7], ['060710080021000', 7], ['060710080021000_2', 7], ['060710080021000_2', 7], ['060710080021000_2', 7], ['060710080021000_2', 7], ['060710080021000_2', 7], ['060710080021000_2', 7], ['060710080021000_2', 7], ['060710080021000_3', 1]]
```

Comment: You area great bro! , Thank you for your time and help. I will be cheking this!

Answer (score 0):

```
# arr is the input( list of list)
output = []
n = len(arr)
i=0
while i<n:
    ID, f = arr[i]
    mul = 1
    while mul*7 < f:
        if mul!=1:
            newID = ID + '_' + str(mul)
        else:
            newID = ID
        temp = [[newID,7] for j in range(7)]
        mul += 1
        output += temp

    rem = f - ((mul-1)*7)
    newID = ID +  '_' + str(mul)
    temp = [[newID, rem] for j in range(rem)]
    output += temp

    i += f

print(output)
```

The code above gives the output as expected.

Comment: Khushhall! Thank for your time and help!. I will try this code!

Answer (score 0):

My solution would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.columns = ['ID', 'counter']

df.counter = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() // 7

df.loc[df.counter>0, 'ID'] += '_' + (df.counter + 1)[df.counter>0].astype(str)
df.counter = df.applymap(lambda id: (df.ID==id).sum())['ID']
```

That's all - Finished.

In the following I'll explain every step:

To prepare your data for processing in pandas, load the library and put the data into a dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.columns = ['ID', 'counter']
```

Initially the counter is set to modulo 7 of the cumulative counter of the IDs in the dataset, which can be used for indexing subgroups of size seven:

```
df['counter'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() // 7
```

Now your dataset looks like this:

```
                 ID  counter
0   060710080013011        0
1   060710080013011        0
2   060710080013011        0
3   060710080013011        0
4   060710080013011        0
5   060710080013011        0
6   060710080013011        0
7   060710080013011        1
8   060710080013011        1
9   060710080013033        0
10  060710080013033        0
11  060710080013033        0
12  060710080013033        0
13  060710080013033        0
14  060710080013033        0
15  060710080013033        0
16  060710080013033        1
17  060710080021000        0
18  060710080021000        0
19  060710080021000        0
20  060710080021000        0
21  060710080021000        0
22  060710080021000        0
23  060710080021000        0
24  060710080021000        1
25  060710080021000        1
26  060710080021000        1
27  060710080021000        1
28  060710080021000        1
29  060710080021000        1
30  060710080021000        1
31  060710080021000        2
```

Now change the IDs, i.e. only if `counter>0` append "counter+1" as a string with a preceding underscore to the existing ID:

```
df.loc[df.counter>0, 'ID'] += '_' + (df.counter + 1)[df.counter>0].astype(str)
```

To change the counter back to the desired sum of IDs, apply a lambda function to each element which returns the sum over all occurences in the dataset of this element:

```
df.counter = df.applymap(lambda id: (df.ID==id).sum())['ID']
```

Then the dataset looks like this:

```
                   ID  counter
0     060710080013011        7      
1     060710080013011        7      
2     060710080013011        7      
3     060710080013011        7      
4     060710080013011        7      
5     060710080013011        7      
6     060710080013011        7      
7   060710080013011_2        2      
8   060710080013011_2        2      
9     060710080013033        7      
10    060710080013033        7      
11    060710080013033        7      
12    060710080013033        7      
13    060710080013033        7      
14    060710080013033        7      
15    060710080013033        7      
16  060710080013033_2        1      
17    060710080021000        7      
18    060710080021000        7      
19    060710080021000        7      
20    060710080021000        7      
21    060710080021000        7      
22    060710080021000        7      
23    060710080021000        7      
24  060710080021000_2        7      
25  060710080021000_2        7      
26  060710080021000_2        7      
27  060710080021000_2        7      
28  060710080021000_2        7      
29  060710080021000_2        7      
30  060710080021000_2        7      
31  060710080021000_3        1
```

Comment: Thanks!! , this is incredible. I will try this in Jupiter notebook.

Comment: I'm glad if it suits you - and i had fun improving it! :-) However - I hardly can see sth really useful in it... Don't get me wrong, but: are you sure that you have a task for which this is the best solution?

Comment: Lol - misunderstood! I didn't want to reject your acception, I was happy about it! :-) I just wanted to know, what's the usecase for this Algorithm, because I have no idea!

Comment: So basically I am using this code for something call CASPER methodology. I am a GIS analyst and I need this code to accomplish bigger set os instructions in the extrapolation process of CASPER. Right now I will choose the options of @James for my python desktops tool, but your solutions fit perfect for the Online version of my tool that uses jupiter notebooks.